# How to pass the body using powershell routes.jason

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, vmware, powershell-3.0, powercli

I'm trying to expose an endpoint using RestPS routes in powershell. I was able to expose it and run a custom PS script when an endpoint (http://localhost:8080/scan) is hit.

How do we pass body through routes & based on that value I need to execute the custom script.

RestPSroutes.json - Example

```
{
    "RequestType": "GET",
    "RequestURL": "/scan",
    "RequestCommand": "C:/RR/api-compliance.ps1"   }
```

snippet from the above script (api-compliance.ps1) ;

```
###############
# Setup Creds #
###############

$userID = "****"
$Pass   = "*****"
#$Creds  = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userID,$Pass
$vCenter = "vCenter01"
$cluster = "Cluster01"
$vmhost = "Host01"
$bl = "Baseline01"

######################
# Connect to vCenter #
######################

Connect-VIServer $VCTRs -user $userID -password $Pass -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -Force




   $baseline = Get-Baseline | ? {$_.name -eq $bl}
 
   $baseline |  Attach-Baseline -Entity $vmhost -Confirm:$false 
Scan-Inventory -Entity $vmhost
```

Right now we are hardcoding the below values

```
  $vCenter = "vCenter01"
    $cluster = "Cluster01"
    $vmhost = "Host01"
```

But we want these to be passed as a request body. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare parameters `$RequestArgs` and `$Body` in the target script/function, and `RestPS` will automatically pass the appropriate values along as strings:

```
param(
  [string]$RequestArgs,
  [string]$Body
)

$RequestArgs.Split('&') |ForEach-Object {
  $paramName,$paramValue = $_.Split('=')
  Write-Host "Received query parameter ${paramName} with value '$paramValue'"
}
```